# Draw rectangles on top of a picture in JavaFX2

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to draw rectangles on a picture using mouse events in JavaFX2.

Right now, I have an ImageView in a StackPane and I add Rectangles over it. The problem is even if I set the Rectangles' X and Y to the MouseEvent X and Y, the Rectangles' stay centered in the StackPane.

I guess it's the StackPane that centers every child by default, but I can't find a decent solution to the problem. Could you guys please point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
@FXML
private StackPane stack_pane;

private final ImageView image_view = new ImageView();

private final Set<Rectangle> rectangles = new HashSet<Rectangle>();

private final SimpleDoubleProperty selectionRectInitialX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private final SimpleDoubleProperty selectionRectInitialY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

private final SimpleDoubleProperty selectionRectCurrentX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
private final SimpleDoubleProperty selectionRectCurrentY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

private Rectangle selectionRect;

@Override
public void initialize(final URL fxmlFileLocation, final ResourceBundle resources)
{
    this.stack_pane.getChildren().add(this.image_view);
    this.selectionRect = this.getRectangle();

    this.selectionRect.widthProperty().bind(this.selectionRectCurrentX.subtract(this.selectionRectInitialX));
    this.selectionRect.heightProperty().bind(this.selectionRectCurrentY.subtract(this.selectionRectInitialY));

    this.stack_pane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent event)
        {
            MainWindowController.this.selectionRect.xProperty().set(event.getX());
            MainWindowController.this.selectionRect.yProperty().set(event.getY());
            MainWindowController.this.selectionRectInitialX.set(event.getX());
            MainWindowController.this.selectionRectInitialY.set(event.getY());
        }
    });

    this.stack_pane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent event)
        {
            MainWindowController.this.selectionRectCurrentX.set(event.getX());
            MainWindowController.this.selectionRectCurrentY.set(event.getY());
            MainWindowController.this.repaint();
        }
    });

    this.stack_pane.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent event)
        {
            final Rectangle newRect = MainWindowController.this.getRectangle();

            newRect.setWidth(MainWindowController.this.selectionRect.getWidth());
            newRect.setHeight(MainWindowController.this.selectionRect.getHeight());
            newRect.setX(MainWindowController.this.selectionRect.getX());
            newRect.setY(MainWindowController.this.selectionRect.getY());

            MainWindowController.this.selectionRectCurrentX.set(0);
            MainWindowController.this.selectionRectCurrentY.set(0);

            MainWindowController.this.rectangles.add(newRect);
            MainWindowController.this.repaint();
        }
    });
}

public Rectangle getRectangle()
{
    final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setFill(Color.web("firebrick", 0.4));
    rect.setStroke(Color.web("firebrick", 0.4));
    return rect;
}

public void repaint()
{
    this.stack_pane.getChildren().clear();
    this.stack_pane.getChildren().add(this.image_view);
    this.stack_pane.getChildren().add(this.selectionRect);
    for (final Rectangle rect : this.rectangles)
    {
        this.stack_pane.getChildren().add(rect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change StackPane to AnchorPane.  AnchorPane allows you to set the X, Y of each child relative to the Pane.  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html

Comment: Wow, it was so simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Alignment of StackPane:

StackPane.setAlignment(selectionRect, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html) for the value reference of Pos class.